# Is it possible to update a varible from one shell to another shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can we update a variable from one shell to another shell ?

Suppose , I am having 2 Putty sessions opened , I want to set a variable in the first SHELL and I need that variable to access from the 2nd SHELL .

Is is possible ?

Comment: No it is not possible but if you tell us what you're trying to do then probably we can suggest you alternatives.

Comment: Just want to know possiblility ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each process' environment is protected, there's no way to share environment variables.  I would suggest using a file on a shared filesystem to store the variable you want and reading that file in whenever you'd need to know what the new value is.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the variable to a script.
Then source the script in the 2nd session.

For example:

```
# session 1
hello=world
echo "hello=$hello" > /tmp/var.sh

# session 2
. /tmp/var.sh
echo $hello
```

Comment: good idea ! nice

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not possible, because each shell (and each process) has its own environment. See [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

However, you might want to switch to the [`fish` shell](http://fishshell.com/). It gives you so called [universal variables](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables) which might be shared between several instances of (i.e. processes running) the `fish` shell. This is implemented thru the [fishd](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#fishd) user daemon (with which every `fish` process communicates).