# Is it possible to define a variable as static in shell bash function like C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

In C, I can define a static variable in a function like this

```
int func() {
    static int var=0
    .....
}
```

Is there something equivalent to that in shell bash linux?

Is it possible to define a local variable of the bash shell function as static?

Comment: Modulo time of initialization (which probably doesn't matter for your use case) and scope (which can be ignored/worked around), this is simply a global variable, so if all else fails you can use that.

Comment: @delnan I've never heard the word modulo used in this way.

Comment: Why you want to do this? Maybe we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: It is not clear to me what would be the analogue of static variables in a shell; I see at least two ways of understanding: a variable shared between several shell functions in the same shell process (then use any non `local` shell variable), or a variable shared between several shell processes.

Comment: In fact I want to keep the variable as local in the function and in the same way and I want to keeep it global. so each time I call the function I get the value of the las call of the function

Comment: I would just use a global variable. `bash` isn't designed for this kind of engineering practice.

Comment: ksh93 . support `typeset -r varname` from the manpage: "-r
    The given vnames are marked readonly and these names cannot be changed by subsequent assignment." Use `echo ${.sh.version}` to confirm you have a ksh93+ version Good luck.

Comment: @m0skit0 A simple thing which I just wanted to try and which is hard in bash: Count the number of invocations of a command by wrapping it with a simple function which increments a counter, no matter whether it is executed in a subshell (e.g. in a pipe) or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `bash` you cannot really get that (I imagine you want some variable shared between several instances of your shell...). However, if you switch to the [fish](http://fishshell.com/) shell (use `chsh` to change your login shell), you get so called *universal* variables which kind-of fits the bill. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20740691/841108) to a related question.

BTW, you should read [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and consider using `bash` functions (instead of a script).

If you just want to share a variable between several shell functions inside the *same* shell process, just don't declare it `local` to functions!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the static variable to be used within a bash function and to have the life of the bash script you can define and initialize it before the function, making it global, and then use it, without initialization, within the function. The value will have the life of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

variable=0

increment()
{
    (( variable++ ))
    echo $variable
}

while true; do
    increment
    sleep 1
done
```

This will output an incrementing number.

Answer (score -2):

What are you planning to actually achieve? If it is something like a variable which can  store values between shell script executions, you can export the variable using export command. This will make it a globally accessible environment variable.

As is the case with statics, you will have to make sure nobody else is updating it except your code.

Comment: C static does not store values between executions.

Comment: The question is around a static variable defined in a method. In C, static variable defined inside a method does keep the value between different method executions. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Answer (score -5):

The only reason to have a static variable in bash would be to protect it from "bad coding", and if that becomes a problem, you're not testing at each step of the way like you should be.

Just use a pre-defined global variable, and keep two copies of the script, ie: TestScript and Script. When you've tested the changes to TestScript, copy and paste the changes into Script.

You should also be doing all of your testing when possible in a VM.

I've done this and I've now got a script that customizes a barebones Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server to include a clients new hostname, fqdn, email forwarding for root and webmaster, and installs and configures ownCloud, MariaDB 10, PHP 7, Apache 2, Webmin, mod_security, mod_evasive, tripwire, rkhunter, chkrootkit, PSAD, ClamAV, Logwatch, sets the firewall and file permissions, sets logfile rotation, resets the root password, generates Expect scripts to be called on the fly, truncates the logs and removes generated script files, then reboots the server for use.

I'll be adding additional functions to allow selecting Samba and LDAP as additional features during install, and modifying the install as needed.

Just takes a lot of time and a lot of testing.